# Android: add prebuild object files

Tags: makefile, android-ndk

I'm building static library with ndk-4 and assembler coredumps on some of my assembly files. I used codesourcery assembler to create objects for these files. Now, I have no clue how to add these prebuild object files to the project. I tried to check inside their makefiles, but I don't see anything. I tried to add them to LOCAL_OBJECTS

```
    LOCAL_OBJECTS    += $(NEON_LOCAL_OBJECTS)
```

but it doesn't work. The value LOCAL_OBJECTS is reset to nothing inside build/core/build-binary.mk

Most likely I'd be able to avoid that problem by swithing NDK, or build workstation (I'm using windows), but for now I only want to fix that simple problem by adding preassembled objects to the static library.

If that's impossible to do, maybe somebody can say what kind of rule I could add so that after my static library is build my rule kick-in and adds my preassembled files to the target lib?
Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into the same problem. After much googling I may have just stumbled onto the answer, although I haven't had the time to try it out yet. [This](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/bfa9ea0d89d5573f) is the Google Groups question where a similar question is posted, the poster is advised to archive the object files into a library (e.g. libfoo.a) and link that. [Here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_22.html) is an article I found on archiving the object files into a library. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I agree, that's was my conclusion. After reading their makefiles it became clear that I can't do it without modifying NDK build scripts. That's retarded when yet another app comes up with their own "smart" build system. Totally hate that shit... My conclusion is that android build system absolutely has to be avoided for complex big projects. Plain clear makefile should be used instead. I wasted more time reading their crap-ware than actually coding.

Comment: Actually, I made a workaround for my problem. Instead of trying to fix the build I updated my asm code. Assembler from Windows-NDK-4 crashes on vadd.s32 and vsub.s32 neon instructions. I had like 10 of them, I simply emit binary machine code in place of these instructions for their broken GCC.

Comment: Proving a link to a long thread or an article shouldn't be an answer without  providing something else.