# Use ARMCC to compile Android native library

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, armcc

I've been working on an Android project which has several native C++ libraries. Compiling and debugging using Eclipse with ADT plugin works well. Obviously Android NDK uses arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc of some version to compile the native libraries.

Since I've been using NEON intrinsics heavily, I would like to try to compile the native libraries with ARM's official compiler `armcc`. I read everywhere that `armcc` is supposed to give better optimized code when using intrinsics. So I downloaded the trial version of DS-5 from ARM website, just to try and see whether there's really any speed difference.

The DS-5 seems to be just a modified version of Eclipse that uses the ARMCC toolchain, so I installed the ADT plugin. But when I compile using DS-5, it seems that the code is still generated using `gcc` rather than `armcc`.

Do you have any idea how to force DS-5 or Eclipse to build the Android native code using `armcc`? Or is it possible (and how) to build the static NDK libraries from command line and then replace the libraries in my project, so they get deployed to the testing phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ARM DS-5 Community Edition](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/ds-5/compare-arm-ds5-editions.php) doesn't include `ARM compiler` (`armcc`).

If you could get hold of `armcc` best would be to separate your processing heavy algorithms to individual compilation units (separate C files), build them with `armcc` as you would do for any compilation unit. When you get the object files, [convert them into an archive](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_22.html) then use that in Android.mk as `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += <your_archive>`.

You can't use `armcc` plainly to build Android compatible libraries mostly because of `Bionic` dependencies, I think.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. I don't have the community version, but the 30-day trial of the full DS-5 version.

Comment: If I have only one compilation unit to be compiled with armcc, do I still need to put this single .o file into an archive?

Comment: @NumberFour I have looked around and saw a few posts complaining about that and consensus was to create an archive. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/text/PREBUILTS.text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587965/android-add-prebuild-object-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use `armcc` to build Android compatible static libraries even though Android has a different C library (`bionic`). The key is the `--library_interface` flag for `armcc`. According to [the documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472j/chr1359124928908.html):

> Use an option of the form --library_interface=aeabi_* when linking with an ABI-compliant C library. Options of the form --library_interface=aeabi_* ensure that the compiler does not generate calls to any optimized functions provided by the ARM C library.

In addition, there are a few more flags to ensure compatibility with the Android EABI resulting in the following command for an Android `armeabi-v7a` target:
`armcc --library_interface=aeabi_clib --wchar32 --enum_is_int --no_hide_all --cpu=7-A --fpu=softvfp+vfpv3 -c -o libfunc.o libfunc.c`

You can then use `armar --create libfunc.a libfunc.o` to create a static library that can be linked with the Android NDK as `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`.

I have successfully tested this with Android NDK r10d on Android KitKat 4.4.2.